# How to set the cell color dynamically in grid header by it's value

Tags: java, grid, vaadin

I am trying to `dynamically` change the `color` of `header cells`

The columns with header in `grid` are generated dynamically too:

```
for (Employee emp : employees) {
     Grid.Column<Employee> empColumn = grid.addColumn(...).setHeader(emp.getNameWithEmpRelationship());
}
```

But I only know how to change the `color` of whole `header row`, not only for `cell`

My custom `.css` file:

```
:host(.header-change) [part~="header-cell"] {
  background-color: #ececec;
  color: black;
}
```

Then I added it into the `grid`

```
grid.addClassName("header-change");
```

And result looks like:

[image]

But I need to do something like this:

```
for (Employee emp : employees) {
     Grid.Column<Employee> empColumn = grid.addColumn(...).setHeader(emp.getNameWithEmpRelationship());
     
     if(emp.getNameWithEmpRelationship().name().equals("CONTRACT") {
        empColumn.addClassName("orange-cell");
     }

     if(emp.getNameWithEmpRelationship().name().equals("PART_TIME") {
        empColumn.addClassName("green-cell");
     }

     if(emp.getNameWithEmpRelationship().name().equals("FULL_TIME") {
        empColumn.addClassName("blue-cell");
     }

}
```

`.css` should looks like:

```
.orange-cell {
  background-color: orange;
  color: black;
}

.blue-cell {
  background-color: blue;
  color: black;
}

.green-cell {
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
}
```

And the result should looks like (I achieved the sample result by manually adjusting the value of the element through the browser):

[image]

How can I do this? Because my example is not working.

Comment: Just to see if I understand the case correctly. Do you have a 2 rows header grid? The first with the gray background and the 2nd with color (blue/green/orange) color and do you want to customize the 2nd one?

Comment: @kszk you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the short answer is that you can't. While you can apply css classnames, and thus styling, to body cells, using ClassNameGenerator, that does not work for header cells.

What you can do is use a component for the header cells' contents, using `Column.setHeader(Component c);` Then you can of course apply styling whichever way you like to that component.

However, that component is not going to cover the entire space. While it's technically possible to make that happen with css, it's complicated, error prone, and not really supported.

There's a feature request ticket for this here: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/1434. You can vote for the feature by adding a thumbs-up reaction.

Comment: It is so sad ... Because the label as component in column header with background color looks amateurish

Comment: But thank you, i will use font color instead.